# Regex ÅÄÖ in if-statement

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I have an if statement that checks so that someone has entered an input correct and not only whitespace or blank. I also want it to allow for the swedish letters å, ä and ö and not only the letters a - z. I cannot find how to get it right. I appreciate your help!

```
String name;
do {
    System.out.print("name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!name.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again!");
    }
} while
```

Answer (score 5):

Just include them in the allowed character class:

```
if (!name.matches("[A-Za-zåäö]+")) {
```

Comment: Thanks man, realize I should have tried this before. Helpful answer, will upvote asap

Comment: Regex character classes simply list the characters. You can specify ranges with a ``-``, such as ``a-z``. That's the same as writing ``abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz``.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just test if something else than whitespace was entered?

```
\S+
```